# Process Text Files with Python Dictionaries and Upload to Running Web Service lab

Tags: python

I want to write a Python script that will upload the feedback automatically without having to turn it into a dictionary. 
The script should now follow the structure:

- List all .txt files under /data/feedback directory that contains the actual feedback to be displayed on the company's website.
    Hint: Use os.listdir() method for this, which returns a list of all files and directories in the specified path.
- You should now have a list that contains all of the feedback files from the path /data/feedback. Traverse over each file and, from the contents of these text files, create a dictionary by keeping title, name, date, and feedback as keys for the content value, respectively.
- Now, you need to have a dictionary with keys and their respective values (content from feedback files). This will be uploaded through the Django REST API.
- Use the Python requests module to post the dictionary to the company's website. Use the request.post() method to make a POST request to http:///feedback. Replace  with 35.193.233.100.
- Make sure an error message isn't returned. You can print the status_code and text of the response objects to check out what's going on. You can also use the response status_code 201 for created success status response code that indicates the request has succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import os
import requests
 
dir="/data/feedback/"
url= "http://1.1.1.1/feedback/"
#IMPORTANT: Replace 1.1.1.1 with your
#  Qwiklab's "corpweb" IP Address
 
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    tipos = ["title","name","date","feedback"]
    datos = {}
    lineas = []
    print(file)
    with open(dir+"/"+file,"r") as txtfile:
        x = 0
        for line in txtfile:
            datos[tipos[x]] = line.rstrip('\n')
            x += 1
    print(datos)
    response = requests.post(url,json=datos)
```

Comment: no need for the lineas[] empty list tbh, thanks anyways, it helped me

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
import requests

feedbacks_dir = '/data/feedback'
url = 'http://<corpweb-external-IP>/feedback/' #Replace <corpweb-external-IP> with your external ip

files = os.listdir(feedbacks_dir)

for file in files:
  file_obj = open(os.path.join(feedbacks_dir, file), 'r')

  lines = [ line.replace('\n', '') for line in file_obj ]

  feedback_dict = { "title": lines[0], "name": lines[1], "date": lines[2], "feedback": lines[3] }

  res = requests.post(url, data=feedback_dict)

  if not res.status_code == 201:
    print('Something went wrong')

  file_obj.close()
```

Comment: In case if you find the approach of Sushanth Kurdekar confusing a bit.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.